# treepanel in extjs : selection node deselect automatically after click on below area

Tags: extjs4, treepanel, extjs5

i testing treepanel .

select any node in treepanel after click below blank area then selection is remove using framework : Ext js 5.0.1.1255  Crisp.

but change framework :Ext js 5.0.0.970 and older then work perfectly .

fiddle link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9es

Comment: I would classify it as a bug, report it please to Sencha.

Comment: i already send send mail to sencha

Answer (score 0):

Why your treepanel has a height from 800px? If u select a node and click outside of the panel it works correctly (it does not deselect). Remove the height and it works. Imho i do want to deselect if i click inside my treepanel on a "none-node-area" inside of the body! Its a totally correct behaviour imo.

I would definitely NOT call this a bug.

**EDIT:**
Though if you want to disable this behaviour you could do this:

```
listeners: {
    'beforecontainerclick': function(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes in lower version u cannot deselect by clicken in the tree-panel-body area - but imo its not a correct behaviour. I think the "treepanel deselect" usability improved as it is now in the actual version (5.0.1.1255)